# How to combine two sets of data frames with different columns

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have two sets of data frames

df :

|  | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| Label |  |
| adidas | 26% |
| Jordan | 1.6% |
| Asics | 1.7% |

df1 :

|  | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Answer Code Label |  |
| adidas | 11% |
| Jordan | 16% |
| Asics | 1% |

I am trying to create this:

| Label | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| adidas | 26% | 11% |
| Jordan | 1.6% | 16% |
| Asics | 1.7% | 1% |

I have tried various methods and all produce the same error. For example

`df = df.join(df1)`

`df.merge(df1, left_on='Answer Code Label',right_on='Label')`

These are the errors I get :

Cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping
names

KeyError: 'Label'

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: Please check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), otherwise it's unnecessary hard for others to convert your table df and df1 into actual code to cross check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your DataFrames as

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Label': {0: 'adidas', 1: 'Jordan', 2: 'Asics'}, 'col1': {0: '26%', 1: '1.6%', 2: '1.7%'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Answer Code Label': {0: 'adidas', 1: 'Jordan', 2: 'Asics'}, 'col1': {0: '11%', 1: '16%', 2: '1%'}})
```

You can either use `.merge()` with `right_on` and `left_on` like this

```
df1.merge(df2, right_on='Answer Code Label', left_on='Label')
```

Or make sure the columns have the same name and then use the `on` parameter

```
df2.columns = ["Label", "col1"]
df1.merge(df2, on='Label')

    Label col1_x col1_y
0  adidas    26%    11%
1  Jordan   1.6%    16%
2   Asics   1.7%     1%
```

Comment: Than you this worked but I needed to reset the index I think it was because i had a multilevel columns.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to merge on the indices of the dataframes, you can pass `True` to `left_index` and `right_index` parameters to `merge` , and the type of merge you are looking for is inner merge:

```py
>>> out=df1.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
>>> out.index.name=df.index.name  # Optional (If need index name)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
       col2  col1
Label            
adidas  11%   26%
Jordan  16%  1.6%
Asics    1%  1.7%
```

Comment: Hello unfortunately I get the error "cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names"